# React native webview crashes on optional check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, webview

when I'm entering a screen, the app just crashes / closes immediately when it's doing this check. It's checking for if webivew is true or false.

Any reason why?

```
const [webview, setWebview] = useState(false);

{webview ? (
          <View>
            
            <WebView
              style={{  height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
              source={{ uri: "https://www.google.com/" }}
            />
          </View>
        ) : null}
```

Comment: Have you imported webview?

Comment: I have, just didn't include it here...

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, i'm using expo go and it works fine there. But when i'm building the app too android, it closes the app when i'm entering a screen with webview like the one above.

Comment: try looking at your logs